# How to change the Windows phone 8 official map control culture?

Tags: c#, xaml, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8, dictionary

I want to change the culture of the Controls:Map windows phone 8 map control, with the bing maps control I could simply do map.culture = "en-GB" or whatever, how can I do this with the windows phone 8 map?

Answer (score 0):

I think Map's [Language](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windowsphone/develop/system.windows.frameworkelement.language%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) property can be it what you are looking for.

Comment: I want to change the actuall text on the map to Russian, this isnot working: